# Is it possible to resize/fullscreen the window in The Wonderful End of the World?

Tags: the-wonderful-end-of-the-world

I just bought The Wonderful End of the World in a Steam sale.

Unfortunately, I'm trying to play it on a laptop, which has pretty low vertical resolution.

So parts of the game content are hiding above/below the screen and are inaccessible.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently yes; hitting Alt + Enter switches to fullscreen and resizes the content to suit.